# BCP - Include terminator in data insert

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm using BCP to load a json file to SQL Server (yes I know there are better ways, but need to try this)

The problem is, the json document is not formed properly because the terminator in the format file is being removed, but I want it included

```
bcp db.dbo.test IN G:\JSON\json.out  -f G:\JSON\formatfile.out -T
```

format file terminator:

```
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="] }" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AI"/>
```

How can I end the file without truncating the json closing tags?

Answer (score 1):

BCP is not designed for importing a file into a single column, so you run into these problems. To import a file as a single object, use the OPENROWSET(... SINGLE_BLOB) functionality, like this:

```
INSERT INTO JsonTable(jsonColumn)
SELECT BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ‘TextFile Path’, SINGLE_BLOB) FileName
```

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned I know there are correct/better ways for this. However I still need to implement it with bcp. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely, positively must use BCP, there is one trick that is often used for XML files that should work for JSON files as well.

1. Do not add a Row terminator value
2. Make your Field terminator value something that absolutely, positively, cannot exist in the JSON file, such as '\0~\0\0~' (which is NULL + ~ + two NULLs + ~). If this could exist in the JSON, try some other value. Just ensure that it can't exist in the file.

By default, this imports an entire XML file as a unit. It *should* work on JSON files as well, but I cannot guarantee that.